How to filter a list of String when using SwiftData
I have a model like this:
@Model
final class MyModel: Identifiable, Equatable,ObservableObject {
    @Attribute(.unique) public let id: UUID
    ...
    var searchables: [String] = []

descriptor.predicate = #Predicate<MyModel> { item in
   item.searchables.contains(where: { $0.localizedStandardContains(searchQuery) })
}

However, it gives me the following error:
Can't have a non-relationship collection element in a subquerySUBQUERY...

What is the correct way to perform this kind of query? Is it even supported in SwiftData?

This was asked just a few days ago.

Unrelated but you don't need to conform to any of those protocols, the Model macro will add conformance to PersistentModel and Observable where the former extends both Identifiable and Hashable

Thanks. I did search before, but didn’t find it.

This article may be relevant https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftdata/using-structs-and-enums-in-swiftdata-models

However, there is a catch: if you use collections of value types, e.g. [String], SwiftData will save that directly inside a single property too. Right now it’s encoded as binary property list data, which means you can’t use the contents of your array in a predicate.


I was a bit confused because the article stated that the predicate supports:
Sequence operations (allSatisfy(), filter(), contains(), contains(where:), starts(with:), max(), min())
So I came here to double check.
